# Programatically open and close an expanded row with a button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've created a table with expanded rows based on this example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sorting?file=app%2Fcdk-detail-row.directive.ts

I would like to expand and close row on button (icon arrow_down, arrow_up), not by clicking on all row.

For example :

When I click on icon in row it expand or close

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="arrow">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">   
        <i class="material-icons" 
           (click)="onToggle()" >
          keyboard_arrow_down
        </i> 
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

I'm stuck at that point and I do not know what to do..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a clean solution, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440282/angular-material-table-expand-row-on-column-icon-click) there is a bit of a hacky workaround.

I modified your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sort-k1ebzu?file=app/table-example.html) and I think it replicates what you are trying to do pretty well.

In the template you need to call `stopPropagation` on the click event on the cells:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
```

The icon is set based on an additional property on the data model I added (`state`):

```
{{element.state === 'expanded' ? 'keyboard_arrow_up' : 'keyboard_arrow_down'}}
```

And whether or not the row is expanded is based on that property as well:

```
<div class="mat-row detail-row" [@detailExpand]="element.state" style="overflow: hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the element reference to the function

```
(click)="onToggle(element,i)"
```

and there do this:

```
onToggle(element: YourDataObject, index) {
    this.expandedElement = this.expandedElement == element ? null : element;
}
```

Of course, your expandable details should go something like this:

```
[@detailExpand]="row == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
```